# Switch screen when screen sharing with Google Hangouts

Tags: google-hangouts

Is it possible to change screen when screen sharing with Google Hangouts, without having to restart the screen sharing? (I have a multi-monitor setup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to change screen when screen sharing with Google Hangouts, without having to restart the screen sharing.